# difference between linear map basis and vector basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A linear map can be represented as a matrix in a certain basis P. Similarly, given a vector space over a field, its basis can be found, say Q. How is the concept of P related to that of Q? Are they equivalent concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. And, in fact, what you say includes several inaccuracies or misconceptions. In the second case, you are talking about a specific single vector space- but you cannot find **its basis**.  Any vector space necessarily has an infinite number of different bases. In the first case, with a linear transformation you have two vector spaces (it is, of course, possible to have a linear transformation from one vector space to itself but it is still simplest to treat the "domain" and "range" as separate vector spaces).  You can then choose bases for each (even if domain and range are the same vector space, you can choose different bases for them).  To find the matrix representing a linear transformation [b]in those bases[/b], apply the linear representation to each basis vector for the domain space, in turn, writing the result as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the range space.  The coefficients form a column in the matrix representation of the linear transformation.

For example, consider the linear transformation, from R^2 to R^2 that maps (x, y) to (x+ y, 2x- y).  The "standard" basis for R^2 is {(1, 0), (0, 1)}.  If we take that as basis for both spaces, (1, 0) is mapped to (1+ 0,2(1)- 0)= (1, 2)= 1(1, 0)+ 2(0, 1) which gives the column $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.  (0, 1) is mapped to (0+ 1, 2(0)- 1)= (1, -1)= 1(1, 0)- 1(0, 1).  That gives column $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$.  Putting those together, the matrix representing this linear transformation is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

But we could also choose (1, 0) and (0, 1) as basis vector for the domain and (1, 1), (1, -1) as a basis for R^2 as the range (that this **is** a basis follows from the fact that $(x, y)= \frac{x+y}{2}(1, 1)+ \frac{x-y}{2}(1, -1)$).  Now, (1, 0) is transformed into (1, 2) and (0, 1) is transformed into (1, 2) and (1, -1) as before but now $(1, 2)= \frac{3}{3}(1, 1)- \frac{1}{2}(1, -1)$ and (1, -1)= 0(1,1)+ 1(1,-1) so **in these bases**, the linear transformation is represented by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: That is a very clear exposition. I clearly had some misconceptions earlier. Thanks for clearing them.